# Open AdBrite ads in a New Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom, click

I`ve thoroughly searched for an answer before asking this question, but nothing at all. I want my AdBrite ad to open in a new window when clicked. Please help me. Here is my ad code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>AdBrite Ad Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var AdBrite_Title_Color = '025581';
    var AdBrite_Text_Color = '2D2D2D';
    var AdBrite_Background_Color = 'FFFFFF';
    var AdBrite_Border_Color = 'FFFFFF';
    var AdBrite_URL_Color = '0375B1';
    try{var AdBrite_Iframe=window.top!=window.self?2:1;var AdBrite_Referrer=document.referrer==''?document.location:document.referrer;AdBrite_Referrer=encodeURIComponent(AdBrite_Referrer);}catch(e){var AdBrite_Iframe='';var AdBrite_Referrer='';}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,83,67,82,73,80,84));
    document.write(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=1860199&zs=3330305f323530&ifr='+AdBrite_Iframe+'&ref='+AdBrite_Referrer+'" type="text/javascript">');
    document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,47,83,67,82,73,80,84,62));</script>
    <div><a target="_top" href="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=1860199&afsid=1" style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Your Ad Here</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the jquery ['attribute startswith' selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('a[href^="http://www.adbrite.com"]').live('click',function(){
    $(this).attr('target','_blank'); return true;
});
```

this is assuming the links look like the last `<a>` element in your sample code.

the .live() ensures that links created later will also get the click event. You should check if al urls start with `http://www.adbrite.com` or else they will not get the click event.

Comment: Thank you Willem, but this work only for the link in <div>, how to get this work also for links which will be created after document.write?

Comment: It does, the .live() attaches the click event to every link with [href^="http://www.adbrite.com"], also when created later. Maybe the url is different (ads.adbrite.com or similar)?

Comment: Yes, url is different. I tried to change it to click.adbrite.com which i get from loaded ad source,but still nothing. Can you please save my ad code as a temp html page and execute to check where is a problem?

Comment: your code seems to be incomplete... It does not show any other links, and I already added jquery and the missing script tag.

Comment: Yes, it was incomplete. I already corrected the code and replaced with the full page code which is executes successfully. Please check again.

Comment: I see, the ad runs in an iframe on another domain, so you don't have any javascript rights on that iframe... seems impossible then.

Comment: Ok, any suggested tricks to fetch content through curl or file_get_contents and after play with source?

Comment: Difficult because the ad click counters might fail, and then the ads won't generate any revenue...